# Not able to Set cookie in Code-igniter

Tags: php, cookies, codeigniter-3

**I'm not able to generate cookie the below code works only for only else part.**

```
public function set(){
          $cookie = array(
              'name' => 'demo',
              'value' => 'hello i m saved cookie',
              'expire' => '86500'

          );//EOF array
          if($this->input->set_cookie($cookie))
          {
             $data = array( 'message' => 'cookie successfully set');
              $this->load->view('cookies_view',$data);
          }
          else{
              $data = array( 'message' => 'Something went wrong while creating cookie');
              $this->load->view('cookies_view',$data);
          }
```

Comment: did u checked the solutions?

Comment: I did not found any correct solution to this problem, I'm able to set cookie, but now i'm not able to get cookie. I tried //$data = array( 'message' => $this->input->get_cookie('demo1')); but its NOT WORKING. So i found the temporary solution by $data = array( 'message' => $_COOKIE['demo1']);

Comment: u can only get cookie in CI, by using `get_cookie('demo')`

Comment: yeah its working fine.. Thanks alot. :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value already stored in cookie, `$this->input->set_cookie($cookie)` this will only create the cookie. If you want to check cookie value set or not than you can use like that:

```
$cookie = array(
  'name'   => 'demo',
  'value'  => 'Hello i m cookies which saved in this broswer',
   'expire' => '86500',
);
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);

if(isset(get_cookie('demo'))){ // check cookie value
  echo "success"; // replace with your code
}
else{
  echo "failed"; // replace with your code
}
```

`get_cookie('demo')` will return the cookie value.

You can also explore the [CI Manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html).

Make sure, you are using cookie helper in your file, you must need to include cookie helper:

```
$this->load->helper('cookie');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

this function returns NULL thats why your condition is not working fine. your cookie is being set

use `$this->input->cookie('your cookie name')` to check your condition

```
public function set()
{
    $this->load->helper('cookie');
    $cookie = array(
      'name'   => 'demo',
      'value'  => 'Hello i m cookie',
      'expire' => '86500'
    );
    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
    if ($this->input->cookie('demo')) {
        $data['data'] = array('message' => 'cookie successfully set');
        $this->load->view('your view', $data);
    } else {
        $data['data'] = array('message' => 'Something went wrong while creating cookie');
        $this->load->view('your view', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: true my friend. :)

Comment: Now m not able to get my cookie.  public function get(){
      
       if($this->input->set_cookie('demo'))
      {
        $data = array( 'message' => $this->input->get_cookie('demo'));
        $this->load->view('cookies_view',$data);
      }
      else{
          $data = array( 'message' => 'Cannot get cookie');
          $this->load->view('cookies_view',$data);
      }
  }//EOF GET

Comment: by using `$this->input->cookie('demo')` ?

Comment: Read what i said ! `$this->input->set_cookie('demo'))` this function returns nothing that's why the condition is not working

Comment: this is not the way to use this function `$this->input->get_cookie('demo'));' @devpro has answered you how to use this function.

Comment: by using $this->input->cookie('demo') i'm able to set my cookie. but when im trying to get/ delete my cookie in the same page it shows me CANNOT GET/DELETE COOKIE.

Answer (score 0):

In my case after hours of debugging I realized that cookie_secure was set to true for local development.

So, do an easy check ;

If domain is not https and cookie_secure is set TRUE in config.php, cookies simply will not be set. Change to FALSE and it will be set in both http and https.